# Como capturar o código CMC7 com a API Tesseract?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

Para contextualizar o meu problema, estou fazendo leitura de caracteres em imagens utilizando a API do Tesseract para Java, **tess4j**. Mais especificamente, as imagens são de cheques bancários, onde eu preciso capturar o código [CMC7](http://www.techbr.com.br/seguranca/o-que-o-cmc7-o-cdigo-de-barras-do-cheque/). O que ocorre, é que a API não consegue reconhecer o tipo de fonte do código. Realizei diversas pesquisas, implementei o código que faz a leitura, porém não obtive sucesso. Segue:

**Imagem para leitura:**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File imageFile = new File("D:/teste.png");
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract(); // JNA Interface Mapping
        instance.setLanguage("mcr");
        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

O arquivo fonte utilizado é o *mcr.traineddata*.

Após a leitura da imagem acima, me é retornado o seguinte código:
*d8d0225255dd5582251558825 8515812888828888888858811118580112691188655888 212858801168185865810165125812086510*.

Então, o que eu faço ?

Comment: Como assim? Que plano de fundo? Só com essas informações não da pra poder te ajuda. Edite a pergunta e adiciione mais detalhes, se possivel, com o trecho de código que gerou a duvida.

Comment: @Lucas you achieve to capture CMC7 finally ?

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas engines que realizam esse trabalho árduo de manipulação de imagens, tornando a extração de seus caracteres uma tarefa relativamente simples. A mais conhecida é a Tesseract, porém ela não foi desenvolvida em Java. Por esse motivo, iremos utilizar um wrapper JNA chamado Tess4J, que nos permite executar os métodos nativos dessa engine a partir do Java.

Link para baixar o TESS4J:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/?source=typ_redirect

1. Fazendo o download do Tess4J
   Acesse a página do projeto Tess4J e faça o download da versão mais atual.
2. Configurando as bibliotecas
   Descompacte os arquivos abaixo na pasta lib de seu projeto:

   win32-x86/
    win32-x86-64/
    commons-io-2.4.jar
    ghost4j-0.5.1.jar
    jai_imageio.jar
    jna-4.1.0.jar
    junit-4.10.jar
    log4j-1-2-17.jar
    tess4j.jar

Descompacte também a pasta tessdata na raíz de seu projeto:

tessdata/

3. Escrevendo o código de leitura das imagens
   Como exemplo, irei utilizar uma página digitalizada que encontrei através do Google Imagens.

```
package br.com.danilotl.ocr;

import java.io.File;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;

public class ReadImage {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        File imageFile = new File("page.jpg");
        Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
        instance.setLanguage("eng");

        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Vamos analisar os pontos principais do código acima:

```
import java.io.File;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;
```

Aqui realizamos os imports da classe java.io.File, responsável por criar uma representação do arquivo de imagem, e das classes do Tess4J, necessárias para podermos utilizar os métodos de sua API.

```
File imageFile = new File("page.jpg");
```

Aqui criamos um objeto do tipo File, passando em seu construtor o caminho de onde a imagem está localizada. Neste caso, o arquivo page.jpg encontra-se na raíz do projeto.

```
Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
instance.setLanguage("eng");
```

Aqui recebemos uma instância da classe Tesseract, e em seguida definimos o idioma em que o texto de nossa imagem está escrito. Neste caso, o texto da nossa imagem está em inglês. Caso você precise ler outros idiomas (como o português, que possui caracteres acentuados, por exemplo), você deve baixar o arquivo do idioma em questão na seção de Downloads da página do Tesseract, descompactar o arquivo dentro da pasta tessdata, e definir em seu código o idioma correspondente.

```
try {
    String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (TesseractException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Por fim, efetuamos a leitura da imagem através do método doOCR(), passando a imagem como argumento, e depois exibimos o output no Console. Como podemos comparar, a leitura é bem precisa e contém pouquíssimos erros.

Estas informações estão contidas no link abaixo:

http://danilotl.com.br/blog/reconhecendo-caracteres-em-imagens-com-java-e-tess4j/

Comment: Tem em algum lugar do blog uma informação que permita copiar o conteúdo dele para outro lugar? Caso não tenha, poderia dar uma resposta que seja sua mesmo? Ainda que baseada nesse artigo.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo você antes de enviar para o Tesseract realizar a leitura da imagem fazer um processamento de imagem, existem algumas ferramentas que você pode estar utilizando que até no próprio [Wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality) do Tesseract recomenda estar utilizando para aumentar a qualidade/precisão do reconhecimento.

Se as suas imagens tiverem esse padrão (Cinza e apenas números) talvez usando um processamento de imagem do tipo Limiarização e passando como parâmetro para o Tesseract estar identificando apenas número você terá uma melhora muito significativa.

Me baseando em um [projeto feito em C#](https://github.com/andreluizsecco/RecogCaptcha) onde você pode estar manipulando a imagem e depois passando para o Tesseract reconhecer, você pode testar o projeto para compreender seu funcionamento um pouco melhor. No caso desse projeto ele possui o seguinte código:

```
private string OCR(Bitmap b)
        {
            string res = "";
            using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
            {
                engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
                engine.SetVariable("tessedit_unrej_any_wd", true);

                using (var page = engine.Process(b, PageSegMode.SingleLine))
                    res = page.GetText();
            }
            return res;
        }
```

E uma das variáveis você pode montar o "dicionário" do Tesseract, que no seu caso utilize apenas números você poderia estar definindo da seguinte maneira:

```
engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "1234567890");
```

Acredito que pegar a imagem e fazer com que o Tesseract reconheça os caracteres não terá muito sucesso.

[Nesse artigo](https://blog.codeexpertslearning.com.br/lendo-imagens-uma-abordagem-%C3%A0-ocr-com-google-tesseract-e-python-ee8e8009f2ab) cita alguns pontos essências para os caracteres serem extraídos que são:

- Dois canais de cores somente (preto e branco). Seja ela em escala de
  cinza (0≤ Vi≤ 255) ou então a imagem binarizada (Vi== 0 || Vi== 255).
  Vi=Valor de intensidade.
- Texto alinhado/padronizado e sem ruídos (gerados geralmente durante a
  etapa de binarização).
- Altura do box (espaço ocupado pelos caracteres) superior ao mínimo de
  10px.
- Densidade ideal de 300dpi, ou proporcionais para o pressuposto acima.
- Possuir o texto extraível em um único padrão de alfabeto (ou idioma).
- Sem espaço inútil, considerado como bordas para o texto.